# Linux log files - why did my server go down?

Tags: linux, logging, centos-5

When I got home, my server was hung in the BIOS boot process - the system had restarted for some reason.

The last log entry in `/var/log/messages` relates a DHCP renewal request - there's nothing listed after that. I have viewed all of the files edited since the server went down (sometime after 4:10PM EST on May 27).

Are there any specific log files I can check to help determine why the server went down? I am running CentOS 5.6. I have also sorted the files in `/var/log` by modify date and read all logs which were modified on or after May 27th. I also do not see any `*.err` files in `/var/log`.

Comment: CentOS 5.6. I should have been more specific before - I sorted the files in /var/log by modify date and read all logs which were modified on or after May 27th. I also do not see any *.err files in /var/log.

Comment: What makes you think it was a crash?  why not a power cut or brownout/voltage dip?